# How to correctly reinitiate view with $state.go from another view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-v1

I am attempt to send users from one state to another with this method:

```
$state.go('splash');
```

This works correctly, however, when users are sent to my `splash` view the code does not reinitiate.

This is the html of the splash state:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="splash-screen" scroll="false">
    <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

<script id="login.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list padding">
        <div class="error" ng-if="errors">
          <p ng-bind-html="error_message"></p>
        </div>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="data.password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="login(data)">Login</button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

This is the controller for the view:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('SplashCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, $timeout, $localstorage, appAPI) {

  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.password = '';

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("login.html", {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.login = function(data) {
     alert(data.password);
  };

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $scope.openModal();

  });

});
```

When users visit the `splash` view the first time, the modal loads as intended, however, when they are directed there from the `$state.go` - the modal does not load.

Any thoughts how I can get this to work correctly?

Comment: @georgeawg - I am not sure which data would need to be stored. My end goal is just to have the login screen modal box appear when calling sending users to the splash state.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple Calls to $ionicPlatform.ready()

Unfortunately, other callbacks passed to the function are silently ignored. (ARGH!)<sup>[1](https://bobowen.tech/multiple-calls-to-ionicplatform-ready/)</sup>

In addition to taking a callback function as a parameter, it returns a promise for the platform being ready.

Use the promise:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready().then(function() {

    $scope.openModal();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking to reload your 'SplashCtrl' controller when the user is routed to the 'splash' state. 
If so, try this $state.go('splash', {}, {reload: true});

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your entire project so I can't tell really. It seems your structure is a bit off. You should only have one ionicPlatform.ready() and it should be to setup the environment. Once done it should forward the user to your first view, no open a modal.

This is how I check that in my app. The platform ready function has $state.go('app.calendar'); which is my first view (assuming they are logged in) - if they are not logged in the init function returns an error from the promise and the statechange error code forwards them to the login signup page.

State controller

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    cache: false,
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
    controller: 'TabCtrl',
    resolve: {
        user: function (UserService) {
            var value = UserService.init();
            return value;
        }
    }
})
// Calendar
.state('app.calendar', {
    url: "/calendar",
    cache: true,
    views: {
        'calendar-tab': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/calendar.html',
            controller: 'CalendarController'
        }
    }
})
```

Check if logged in.

```
function init(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (loggedIn()) {
        deferred.resolve(currentUser);
    } else {
        deferred.reject({error: "noUser"});
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

React to the state error - app-first is the login or signup page.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {

        console.log('$stateChangeError ' + error && (error.debug || error.message || error));

        // if the error is "noUser" the go to login state
        if (error && error.error === "noUser") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('app-first', {});
        }
    }
);
```